# How to set binding source to "self"/UserControl Code Behind

Tags: wpf, data-binding

How can I set a Binding Source to point to "this" UserControl CodeBehind? Eg. From a UserControl `MarkdownEditor.xaml`, I want to point to properties within `MarkdownEditor.xaml.cs`. Doing this without setting `DataContext = this`

### Update: My Solution

This is what I did tho I marked @Alex B's solution as answer. I didn't want to set the `DataContext` of the entire control to Self, as I am binding to other objects too

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MarkdownEditor}}, Path=Options.FontFamily}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the following binding:

```
<MarkdownEditor DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using your proposed extensive expression:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MarkdownEditor}}, Path=Options.FontFamily}
```

Isn't it easier just setting `x:Name` of the `UserControl`?

```
<UserControl
        ...
    x:Name="Control">

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=SomeText}" />

</UserControl>
```

Comment: This doesn't always seem to work. It works fine most of the time...but sometimes it fails to find ElementName=Control.

Comment: Well, actually, the alternative solution (find ancestor relative source) also fails in the same scenario so this is a red herring. I had a framework element that was being set to a property on a child element in the user control, but it was not part of the visual tree, hence could not find the root user control. Doh.