# Trying to learn WPF and MVVM and having issues with DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

[Full Code](https://github.com/PBento96/Projeto10790)

Hi, im trying to get this textbox in MyAccountView

```
                                <User_Controls:ClearableTextBox Margin="5"
                                    x:Name="txtUsername"
                                    Placeholder="Username"
                                    Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

to display the currently logged in user set in the VM

```
private string originalUsername;
private string username;

public string Username
{
    get { return username; }
    set
    {
        if (username != value)
        {
            username = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Username));
        }
    }
}

public MyAccountViewModel()
{
    originalUsername = App.CurrentUser;
    Username = originalUsername;
}
```

however when i enter debuggin the data context in the view shows as null

```
public MyAccountView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MyAccountViewModel();
}
```

i have sucessefull replaced text with the .Text atribute in this custom tb in login but when i try to do it here it does nothing

this is a course project i need to do by the end of the mont so any help is deeply apreciated!

ps- user passwords are set to 12345 if you wish to test

setting `txtUsername.Text = App.CurrentUser;` works however i am unable to do it through bindings as the data context appears to be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataContext of the view shouldn't be null since you set it in the constructor of the view.
Otherwise show where you place the breakpoint that show that it is null.
The Binding `Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}"` is not working because you are using an antipattern in your UserControl "ClearableTextBox" constructor.

```
<User_Controls:ClearableTextBox Margin="5"
                                x:Name="txtUsername"
                                Placeholder="Username"
                                Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}"/>



public ClearableTextBox()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Since you set the DataContext of your usercontrol to itself in the constructor it now can't "inherit" the DataContext of the view it is placed in.
You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4202145/13448212) that shows how to do it the correct way.

***Edit to reply to the question in the comment without the length limit:

The DataContext is the default source for a Binding.
So when you write `Text="{Binding Placeholder}` it is equivalent to saying "Bind to the property Placeholder on the source DataContext of this control". Now since you removed `DataContext = this` in the constructor of your UserControl it now inherits the DataContext of the view in which it is placed (so MyAccountViewModel in your example).

MyAccountViewModel doesn't have a property `Placeholder` so the placeholder is blank (you should have a message in the output of your IDE).

Now to fix this you need to fix the `Text="{Binding Placeholder}` so that it uses your UserControl as it's source. To fix it you can use the answer I mentioned previously.
This would give you a Binding like this one :
`Text="{Binding Path=Placeholder RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`
or
`Text="{Binding Path=Placeholder ElementName=myClearableTextBox}` (with the lastone you have to name your UserControl "myClearableTextBox" in your xaml like this : `x:Name="myClearableTextBox"`)

Comment: thanks!

i'm learning this friom scratch and the clearable text box was from a tutorial,
removing DataContext = this; fixes my main issue however the placeholder stops working

could tou EILI5? this is my first time working with wpf and my teacher isn't familiar with it either so no help there

Comment: I edited my answer to try to explain. I just noticed you already did such a Binding on the `Text` property of txtInput in your UserControl ClearableTextBox.
`Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"` => this sets the source of the Binding to the first visual ancestor with the Type "UserControl". This is the same idea as the two variants I suggested in my answer.